# ffmpeg in opencv 2.4

Tags: video, opencv, ffmpeg

I am using opencv, but it is very pick with video types that it will open. I have version 2.4 of opencv and it apparently has ffmpeg support built in, though it does not open any movie files correctly, obj.grab() returns false and retrieve(frame,0) return NULL. So it seems to me that FFmpeg is not working correctly, is there something I need to do to turn it on, from internet searches people seem to suggest that from 2.4 onward it is a non-issue(though apparently not). Any help, all the other threads seem to just aout stop short of the answer for me.

(windows 7, Visual studio 2010, opencv 2.4)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, solved it by copying opencv_ffmpeg241.dll to my executables working directory. I didn't recognize it was missing at first, because I just copied the debug versions of the DLLs (with a "d" at the end of the file name), but this one just comes in one flavour. Also there was no "missing DLL" error when I ran my program, opening VideoCaptures just didn't work.

Comment: I have done that already, it still thinks there is a cap_ffmpeg_v2.hpp:342 somewhere, though there is only one without the '_v2'

Answer (score 0):

Its probably not the answer you're looking for, but I've had a similar problem using 2.4, when i used the 2.3 version instead, it worked just fine again.
I do not know what the problem is, i just know this fixen my issue. hth..

Comment: I will give it a go, will any other things be significantly affected ?

Comment: I can now see that it is an error opening cap_ffmpeg_v2.hpp:342, this is because it does not exist on my computer only cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp exists. though I do not know how to make it use the other version.

Comment: simply copy the old file and rename it. It might fix it.